# React comes back with an unexpected token error when I do a dynamic destructuring of my object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic, destructuring

I'm updating an input field with an onChange event in React.

```
const handleUpdateText = (id, name, text) => {
  const newItems = items.map( item => {
  if (item.id === id) {
    return {...item, [menuLang][name]:text } // <-- error here at ][
  }
  return item;
  } )

  setItems(newItems);
}
```

*name* and *text* and name attribute and value of target input field.

*menuLang* is a state variable (string, eg "en").

The items are something like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  type: "menuitem",
  isVisible: true,
  en: {
    name: "Salad",
    desc: "Fresh, seasonal ingredients",
  },
  price: "10",
},
```

Without dynamic destructuring it work fine:

```
    const newItem = {...item}
    newItem[menuLang][name] = text;
    return newItem;
    // instead of: return {...item, [menuLang][name]:text }
```

Any ideas what's the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [computed property name](https://dev.to/miteshkamat27/computed-property-names-es6-3ae3)

```js
let item={id:1,type:"menuitem",isVisible:!0,en:{name:"Salad",desc:"Fresh, seasonal ingredients"},price:"10"};

console.log(item)

let name = 'name'

let text = "Orange"

let menuLang = 'en'

item = {...item,[menuLang]:{...item[menuLang],[name]:text}}

console.log(item)
```

Comment: So I was just incorrectly destructuring a nested object?

Comment: Yes you were incorrectly doing destruction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a mistake here, but I also didn't think what you want to do is possible via destructuring -  I think you have to go down the route of your second example here.

Answer (score 0):

````
const items = [{id:12,name: 'dj' }];
const handleUpdateText = (id = 12, name='ann', text='sample') => {
  const newItems = items.map((item) => {
const obj = {...item};
  if (item.id === id) {
    return {...obj, [menuLang]: {[name]:[text]}};
  }
  return obj;
  });
console.log('item', newItems);
};```
````